# Iterate over Java ArrayList and execute different methods depending on class

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm relatively new to Java and would appreciate any help regarding the following inquiry. I've defined two classes - for simplicity sake, let's call them `A` and `B`. `Class A` has a method named `methodA`, and `Class B` has a method named `methodB`. The objects of these two classes are contained in an `ArrayList` called `container`. What I need to do is to loop over the `ArrayList` and call different methods depending on the type of object.

This is my code currently:

```
for (Object item : container) {
    if (item instanceof A) {
        item.methodA()
    } else if (item instanceof B) {
        item.methodB() 
    }
}
```

My IDE (NetBeans) won't compile the above code since `item` of type `Object` doesn't have `methodA` or `methodB`. Is there some other way to write the loop to accomplish what I need it to do? Thanks.

Comment: Why you haven't added semicolon after if and else content ???

Comment: you should read about Polymorphism

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a cast. Just because you checked that item is an instance of A (or B) doesn't allow you to call A methods on the item.

```
if (item instanceof A) {
    ((A) item).methodA();
} else if (item instanceof B) {
    ((B) item).methodB();
}
```

In general, though, you may want to consider restructuring your code to avoid this pattern. For example, you could create a common interface of base class which both A and B implement:

```
public interface MyInterface { 
    void doSomething();
}

class A : MyInterface {
    ...
    public void doSomething() { this.methodA(); }
}


class B : MyInterface {
    ...
    public void doSomething() { this.methodB(); }
}
```

Then you could do:

```
List<MyInterface> list = // a list of A's and B's
for (MyInterface item : list) { 
    // use polymorphism to invoke the appropriate method
    item.doSomething(); 
}
```

The [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is another common solution for this type of code which is useful when you want to support a bunch of different common operations across a fixed set of classes without constantly modifying those classes.

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with the *variants* problem, for which Java (and pretty much any other widely-used language) has no good answer.  Scala solves it with case classes, and more academic languages like ML handle it with ease.

All the above answers suggest using if-ladders and casting, which is the tersest solution in Java but which basically gives up complete compile-time safety.  If you don't like casts, you can use a visitor pattern to get around the issue. It's about as verbose as you can get, but it's completely type-safe.

```
interface ABVariantVisitor {
    void visit( A a );
    void visit( B b );
}

interface ABVariant {
    void accept( ABVariantVisitor v );
}

class A implements ABVariant {
    // ...
    void accept( ABVariantVisitor v ) {
        v.visit( this );
    }
    // ...
}

class B implements ABVariant {
    // ...
    void accept( ABVariantVisitor v ) {
        v.visit( this );
    }
    // ...
}

List< ABVariant > container;

// ...

for ( ABVariant item : container ) {
    item.accept( new ABVariantVisitor() {
        @Override void visit( A a ) {
            a.methodA();
        }
        @Override void visit( B b ) {
            b.methodB();
        }
    } );
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution in my opinion. It is very OO, clean, and does not interfere with the original design and implementation of the classes.
ChaseMedallion's answer is good, but it requires change of implementation of the original classes and couple a behavior to a class, which was not supposed to have that behavior in the first place.
Only thing I'm not getting here is why generate a new ABVariationVisitor in every iteration. This can extracted to outside of the loop.

Comment: Anonymous class is indeed not the most efficient implementation, but I wrote it that way to make the new code look as close as possible to the old code.  One of the biggest problems with Visitor is that it's pretty hard to read, especially when factored as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Just do type casting to A or B before calling method on it.Convert item into A or B before calling the method

```
for (Object item : container) {
    if (item instanceof A) {
       ((A) item).methodA();;
    } else if (item instanceof B) {
       ((B) item).methodB();
    }
}
```

Comment: technically correct but the best answer is polymorphism.  There should just be a common method that is implemented differently on the two classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way

```
       if (item instanceof A) {
            ((A) item).methodA();
        } else if (item instanceof B) {
            ((B) item).methodB();
        }
```